# span class in php echo

Tags: magento-1.9

i have this piece of code, but:

1. i would like the span classes to appear when qty is 0
2. do you always need the else, because else i don't want it to do anything

So only when an item is sold out it should show the text SOLD with the span classes.

Thanks.

```
<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left"><span class="out-of-stock">
         <?php 
                $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
                if ($qty == 0) :
                    echo $this->__('SOLD');
                else :
                    echo $this->__('&nbsp;');
                endif;
        ?>
</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class based on condition like this -

```
<?php $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left"><span class="<?php if ($qty == 0) { echo  'out-of-stock'; } ?>">
         <?php 

                if ($qty == 0) :
                    echo $this->__('SOLD');
                else :
                    echo $this->__('&nbsp;');
                endif;
        ?>
</span></span>
```

2.You don't need else always, you can simply use only if like this-

```
if ($qty == 0){
//you can put your condition or whole span here
}
```